# convert string array to list and remove string gives FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

In my Android Applicatio I have an Array of Strings from whom I want to remove Strings.

```
List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dishCategory));
        for (int i = 0; i < dishCategory.length; i++) {
            if (dishCategory[i].equals("Beilagen")) {
                categoryList.remove(i);
            }
            String[] dishCategory = categoryList.toArray(new String[categoryList.size()]);
        }
```

But when I try it it givees:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.hswt.fuca, PID: 19818
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 14, size is 13
 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the built in `Iterator` that is part of your `ArrayList` to iterate through your array. Here is a simple implementation that will do what you want. Also change your `List` back to an array after you finish removing all of the elements. This will make your runtime `O(n)` instead of the current `O(n^2)`

```
List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dishCategory));
Iterator<String> i = categoryList.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   String s = i.next();
   if (s.equals("Beilagen")) {
       i.remove();
   }
}
String [] dishCategory = categoryList.fromArray(String[categoryList.size()]);
```

If your aren't a fan of `Iterators` changing your limit on your `for loop` to be the `List.size()` would also work since it will be reevaluated with each pass through the `for loop` though an `i--` will be needed since the indexes are reevaluated after a remove. Here is that code:

```
List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dishCategory));
for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.size(); i++) {
    if (categoryList.get(i).equals("Beilagen")) {
       categoryList.remove(i);
       i--;
    }      
}
String [] dishCategory = categoryList.fromArray(String[categoryList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're modifying the `List` that you iterate over. An example of where this goes wrong is if your `List` is 2 items long:

```
["Beilagen", "Beilagen"]
```

The first iteration removes the item at index `0`. This modifies the `List` so that it looks like this:

```
["Beilagen"]
```

Then the second iteration wants to remove the item at index `1`, but the length of the list is `1` so this will produce an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` like you see.

A quick and dirty fix for this could be to make the number of items you want to iterate over a variable that you modify during removals like so:

```
List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dishCategory));
int upperLimit = dishCategory.length;
for (int i = 0; i < upperLimit; i++) {
    if (dishCategory[i].equals("Beilagen")) {
        categoryList.remove(i);
        upperLimit--;
        i--;
    }
    String[] dishCategory = categoryList.toArray(new String[categoryList.size()]);
}
```

but I'd recommend using [`listIterator()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#listIterator(int)) if you want clean code, as it was made for this sort of purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dishCategory));
categoryList.removeAll(Arrays.asList("Beilagen"));
dishCategory = categoryList.toArray(dishCategory);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dishCategory.length; i++) {
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dishCategory.length - 1; i++) {
```

---

Remember that all the arrays are 0-indexed so you never have an index as big as the actual length of the structure.